# Tinting GKGameCenterViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I´m using the `GKGameCenterViewController` and I want it to have the same tint color as my app. I tried

```
unifiedExperienceController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
unifiedExperienceController.view.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

but it still shows up with the default blue tint color. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: It us using (on iOS 9 at least) a _UIRemoteView so this is likely to be tricky